# aumentar mes a mes dependiendo de un select de año

Tags: php, date

buenas tardes tengo una pregunta tengo un select en un archivo php de nombre menu historico que selecciona el año del que se quieren ver los datos ese valor se lo mando por javascript y lo cacho en otro archivo que se llama grafico1
en este archivo se muestran por mes los registros solo que no puedo hacer que el mes de la fecha avance mi codigo es el siguiente

```
                $an  = $_GET['idPeriodo'];
                $fecha_inicial =date( "'$an-01-01'");
                $fecha_fin =date( "'$an-01-31'");
                for ($contador = 0; $contador < 12; $contador++) {



         $consultatiempo = "SELECT DISTINCT
          khe.Tiempo,
          khe.Fecha,
          khe.IdProyecto,
          cc.Nombre
          FROM
          k_horasextras AS khe
          INNER JOIN c_proyecto AS cc ON cc.IdProyecto = khe.IdProyecto
            INNER JOIN sie_cat_periodos ON cc.id_periodo_proyecto = sie_cat_periodos.CPE_ID_PERIODO WHERE khe.Fecha > $fecha_inicial AND khe.Fecha < $fecha_fin AND sie_cat_periodos.CPE_ID_PERIODO=$periodo
         ORDER BY
         cc.Nombre ASC
  ;";

                    echo $consultatiempo . "<br>";
                    $resultActividades = $catalogo->obtenerLista($consultatiempo);

                    if (mysql_num_rows($resultActividades) > 0) {




                        while ($rowActividades = mysql_fetch_array($resultActividades)) {

                            $data[$rowActividades['Nombre']][$contador] += $rowActividades['Tiempo'];
                        }
                    }
                            $fecha_fin = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha_fin . "+ 1 month"));                            
                            $fecha_inicial = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($fecha_inicial . "+ 1 month"));




                }
```

el primer mes lo hace bien pero después cambia el año y ya hace el cambio de mes

1. 2018-01-01 2018-01-31
2. 1970-01-01 1970-01-01
3. 1970-02-01 1970-02-01